# Custom blocking priority queue

Tags: c#

I created priority queue which stores messages sent from asp net core controller and
then processes them in [BackgroundService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.backgroundservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-5.0)

The thread which loops through items is blocked when collection is empty.

It might look like reinventing the wheel as there is already [BlockingCollectionOfT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=net-5.0) but I am clueless how to extend that thing to my scenario.

Are there any code smells, concurrency hazards?

Perhaps there might be even better way to do it.

I would like to hear your opinion

Thanks

**Implementation**

```
internal class BPQueue : IBPQueue, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly BaseMessage[] _items;
        private readonly object _syncRoot = new();
        private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _manualResetEventSlim;
        private int _head;

        public BPQueue ()
        {
            _items = new BaseMessage[100];
            _head = -1;
            _manualResetEventSlim = new ();
        }

        public bool TryEnqueue(BaseMessage message)
        {
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                if(_head + 1 == _items.Length)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                _head++;
                _items[_head] = message;
            }

            if (!_manualResetEventSlim.IsSet)
            {
                _manualResetEventSlim.Set();
            }

            return true;
        }

        public IEnumerable<BaseMessage> GetEnumerable(CancellationToken token = default)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                if(_head == -1)
                {
                    _manualResetEventSlim.Reset();
                    _manualResetEventSlim.Wait(token);
                }

                BaseMessage item;
                lock (_syncRoot)
                {
                    item = _items[_head];
                    _items[_head] = null;
                    _head--;
                }

                yield return item;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _manualResetEventSlim.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

**Message base class**

```
 public abstract class BaseMessage : IComparable<BaseMessage>
    {
        public Priority Priority { get; }

        public BaseMessage(Priority priority)
        {
            Priority = priority;
        }

        public int CompareTo(BaseMessage? other)
        {
            if (other == null)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            if (Priority < other.Priority)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if (Priority > other.Priority)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

**How is it used**

Example controller

```
 public class QueueController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBPQueue _queue;

        public QueueController(IBPQueue queue)
        {
            _queue = queue;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddMessage([FromBody] SampleMessage sampleMessage)
        {
            var enqueued = _queue.TryEnqueue(sampleMessage);

            if (!enqueued)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

**Background service**

```
 internal class MessageProcessorHostedService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
        private readonly IBPQueue _queue;

        public TaskQueueHostedService(
            ILogger<MessageProcessorHostedService> logger,
            IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory,
            IBPQueue queue)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
            _queue = queue;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                foreach (var message in _blockingPriorityQueue.GetEnumerable(stoppingToken))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                        using var serviceScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
                        var serviceProvider = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
                        var messageHandler = serviceProvider.GetMessageHandler(message);

                        await messageHandler.HandleAsync(message);

                        stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("Queue has been stopped");
                        break;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError("An error occurred while processing queue", ex);
                    }
                }
            }, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
```

**Priority**

```
  public enum Priority : byte
    {
        High = 0,
        Medium = 1,
        Low = 2
    }
```

Comment: Is there any reason why did you not expose the items via IAsyncEnumerable?

Comment: Btw in your implementation you have defined a TryEnqueue method but you are calling a TryAdd in your controller.

Comment: could you please share with us the source code of `Priority`?

Comment: Thanks, updated answer. I am aware of `IAsyncEnumerable` but I couldn't find good mechanism in `System.Threading` which would block and return task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me share with you my observations related to your current implementation.
Then let me show you how to rewrite it to take advantage of `IAsyncEnumerable`.

### `BPQueue`

#### Init

- readonly field initialization: You don't need the constructor to initialize them, you can do that in-line

```
private readonly BaseMessage[] _items = new BaseMessage[100];
private readonly object _syncRoot = new();
private readonly ManualResetEventSlim _manualResetEventSlim = new();
private int _head = -1;
```

#### `TryEnqueue`

- is there any free space: I think you can better express your intent if write the condition like this

```
if (_head == _items.Length - 1)
```

- Reasoning: `_head` is an array index and you want to avoid over indexing

#### `GetEnumerable`

- infinite loop: At the first glance it is not obvious whether it is an infinite loop or will it terminate in case of cancellation
- If you write your  main loop like this then yet again your intent becomes more clear IMHO

```
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
...
}
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

- Reasoning: Until it is not cancelled do that ... otherwise bubble up the cancellation

### `BaseMessage`

#### `CompareTo`

- If you use [switch expression with case guards](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression) the whole method become more concise

```
public int CompareTo(BaseMessage? other) => other switch
{
    null => -1,
    var msg when msg.Priority > Priority => 1,
    var msg when msg.Priority < Priority => -1,
    _ => 0
};
```

---

Your `GetEnumerator` is blocked whenever there is no message to fetch. Since the introduction of [Async Enumerables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/november/csharp-iterating-with-async-enumerables-in-csharp-8) you can rewrite it to make it non-blocking.

Unfortunately there is no built-in async version of the `ManualResetEvent`

- But [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading/) does define an [`AsyncManualResetEvent`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.asyncmanualresetevent?view=visualstudiosdk-2022)
- As well as the `AutoResetEvent` can be [replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215380/why-no-autoreseteventslim-in-bcl/25823389#answer-25823389) with `SemaphoreSlim`.

Here is my version where I have used `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
internal class BPQueue<T>: IDisposable, IAsyncEnumerable<T> where T: class
{
    private readonly T[] _items = new T[100];
    private readonly object _syncRoot = new();
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim isThereAnyData = new(0,1);
    private int _head = -1;

    public bool TryEnqueue(T message)
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            if (_head == _items.Length - 1)
                return false;
                
            _head++;
            _items[_head] = message;

            if(_head == 0)
                isThereAnyData.Release();
        }

        return true;
    }

    public async IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken token = default)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            if (_head == -1)
                await isThereAnyData.WaitAsync(token);
                
            T item;
            lock (_syncRoot)
            {
                item = _items[_head];
                _items[_head] = null;
                _head--;
            }

            yield return item;
        }

        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    public void Dispose() => isThereAnyData.Dispose();
}
```

- I've initialized the `SemaphoreSlim` with 0 as initial value and 1 as the max
- Inside the `TryEnqueue` I call the `Release` only if the `_head` was `-1` prior this method call
- Inside the `GetAsyncEnumerator` I call the `WaitAsync` if the `_head` is `-1` to wait until there is some data to retrieve
- The class itself implements `IAsyncEnumerable` so the `GetAsyncEnumerator` method returns an `IAsyncEnumerator`

  - Please note there is no need here to define the return type as `Task<IAsyncEnumerator>` to be able to use `async`-`await` inside the method
- I've made your class generic because it was tightly coupled to the `BaseMessage`

Here is the code which I've used for testing:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var _queue = new BPQueue<SampleMessage>();
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new();

    _ = Task.Run(async () => {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        _queue.TryEnqueue(new(Priority.Medium));
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        _queue.TryEnqueue(new(Priority.Medium));
        _queue.TryEnqueue(new(Priority.High));
        await Task.Delay(500);
        _queue.TryEnqueue(new(Priority.High));
    });

    _ = Task.Run(async () => {
        await Task.Delay(1750);
        _queue.TryEnqueue(new(Priority.High));
        await Task.Delay(2300);
        _queue.TryEnqueue(new(Priority.Low));
        _queue.TryEnqueue(new(Priority.High));
        await Task.Delay(300);
        cts.Cancel();
    });

    try
    {
        await foreach (var item in _queue.WithCancellation(cts.Token))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Priority);
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Operation has been cancelled");
    }
}
```

There is a known limitation. The async foreach should start prior the first item is pushed into the queue, since the `SemaphoreSlim` has been initialized with 0.

Comment: Superb! I didn't know about `case guards`. I wonder if that thing compiles down to simple if statements or does something clever. Regarding the limitation, apparently there is [SemaphoreSlim.CurrentCount](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/SemaphoreSlim.cs) which might be used in `TryEnqueue` method.

Comment: @JózefPodlecki If you copy the related code to [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDKgZgAQFMB2BXAWwwAUAnASwHsKAXATwxAwCM6asMBvZDXgCXIBzABYYAvBgAMAGh68AslmDlC4jHFlJeGADKUA7mpg8Avj1SYAhswDONUpYDGNDLAwAhSzayKbNy4JYyNxavOgkFNTk9BFUtAycGIE0ANwYZiihrpie3r7+gQAUZHHRDAAOkfEAlHJcddqxUTESlaX0KXUZdeHkOC4AwpQE5ZakWAAqlIW5Plh+ARyUNMJYpNXiAHwYy6ukGDb60Y7CdSGN2vgANldbGAC0Gg3aAG5jGAQ2ghj6qzgfXwAdCVmgxtiD4ncnllGm99p9vr9cADBMCqmUMAAeJqQsTbR6aC68AD6d0kXU6SBMQA=) then you can see it is compiled to if statements.

Comment: @JózefPodlecki It is also advisable to try to perform Release and Wait calls unconditionally. Since the check and the action are not performed as an atomic operation that's why in case of multithreading it could cause strange behaviours. In this simple case it is not a problem, but you should be aware of it.